# How to connect GitHub account to keybase

Tags: github

How to connect GitHub account to keybase?

Here is why:

> The Big Stellar Space Drop To qualify: you must have a Keybase account
>   registered before this announcement OR if you're new to Keybase, you
>   must connect your Keybase account to a GitHub or HackerNews account
>   that was registered before this announcement. This is to prevent bot
>   signups to Keybase.

Answer (score 0):

In the app (I'm using the Mac version) go to `People` > `Prove your identities` > `Prove your GitHub`

Answer (score 0):

Click on the profile icon, choose view profile, than you will have an option to prove GitHub.